# Is there a way to use a class's private enum value as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, enums

Is there a way to use a value from a class-private enum as a template-value for its templated base class?

Here's an example of what I'd like to be able to do:

```
template<int NumCats> class CatList
{
public:
   CatList() {/* empty */}

private:
   int cats[NumCats];
};

class MyCatList : private CatList<NUM_CATS>
{  
public:
   MyCatList() {/* empty */}

private:
   enum {
      CAT_TABBY = 0,
      CAT_GINGER,
      CAT_CALICO,
      NUM_CATS
   };
};

int main(int, char **)
{
   MyCatList myCats;
   return 0;
}
```

... but the above gives me compile-errors:

```
Jeremys-Mac-Pro:~ jaf$ g++ temp.cpp
temp.cpp:10:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NUM_CATS'
   class MyCatList : private CatList<NUM_CATS>
                                     ^
temp.cpp:11:4: error: expected class name
   {
   ^
2 errors generated.
```

I know that I can move the enum to outside/before the declaration of `MyCatList`, but that makes the enum public, and I'd prefer to hide it as an implementation detail if possible.

Another possible change would be to make `CatList<NUM_CATS>` a private member variable rather than inheriting from it, but in my real code it has some virtual methods that I'd like to override in my subclass, so that doesn't work for me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the enum as a private member of a helper class, with `MyCatList` a friend of that class.  Add that helper class as a private base (to bring the enum symbols into the class), and reference NUM_CATS in the template scoped to the helper class.

```
class MyCatListEnumerator {
    friend class MyCatList;
    enum {
        CAT_TABBY = 0,
        CAT_GINGER,
        CAT_CALICO,
        NUM_CATS
    };
};

class MyCatList : private MyCatListEnumerator, private CatList<MyCatListEnumerator::NUM_CATS>
{  
public:
    MyCatList() {/* empty */}

    int first_cat = CAT_TABBY;
};
```

This declares the enum outside the class, but in a way that is not public.